# Cannot execute commands with super user previleges using PHP ssh2_exec()

Tags: php, linux, ssh

Cannot execute commands with super user previleges using PHP ssh2_exec()

If I want to create a folder test_folder inside /var/www on a remote Linux box, the code and ssh command below seems to be correct but, I am unable to create a folder due to lack of super user previlege. The thing I am confused about it is that I have already included the username and password credentials and I am still unable to execute the command.

```
$con = new SSH2SFTP($addr,
    new SSH2Password($user, $pass),
    22); 
$cmd = "sudo mkdir -p /var/www/test_folder";    
$stream = ssh2_exec($con, $cmd); 
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
fclose($stream);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct, but imagine you are entering the linux command after you ssh into the remote machine. You still need to enter the password the first time you use 'sudo'.

Therefore, you can modify the command as follows:

```
$cmd = "echo '" . $pass . "' | sudo -S " . $cmd;
```

Your code will be like this:

```
$con = new SSH2SFTP($addr,
    new SSH2Password($user, $pass),
    22); 
$cmd = "mkdir -p /var/www/test_folder"; 
$cmd = "echo '" . $pass . "' | sudo -S " . $cmd;
$stream = ssh2_exec($con, $cmd); 
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
fclose($stream);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost all of the commands requiring sudo works with this trick. However, I noticed that an ssh command will not accept passwords using the echo method (either manually via terminal or via ssh2_exec). Although, I don't need to execute ssh inside ssh.